# Start menu wont close when running apps as administrator

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

On my new laptop (Lenovo P53) the start menu will not close after using it to run any program as administrator (either with mouse right click menu or keyboard ctrl-shift-enter).

The UAC dialog pops up, and after confirming it, the app starts, but the start menu stay open and in focus. If I type, the typing goes to the search bar of the cart menu.

Example:

- press WINDOWS key
- type *cmd*
- press ctrl-shift-enter
- in the UAC select YES (cursor left, followed by enter)

Now the CMD window appears (properly as administrator), but also the start menu stays and if continue typeing *xyz*, the it just changes the search string in the start menu to *cmdxyz* (so it is not a gfx glitch).

Windows 10 is up to date, version 1909 build 18363,  drivers are also up to date (via Lenovo Vantage tool)

`sfc /scannow` finds no errors.

Running apps from the start menu normally (not as administrator) works fine.

PS: Other people having the same problem on tenforums.com : [Start Menu Stays Open When App is Run as Administrator](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/161161-start-menu-stays-open-when-app-run-administrator.html)

PPS: The problem happens with all user accounts on this PC. Even newly created ones.

PPPS: There is a similar issue when selecting a recently opened file in Start Menu, but does not happen with all apps. It does not happen with Notepad, but does with Remote Desktop Connection:

- press the WINDOWS key
- type *remo*
- when the Remote Desktop Connection appears and is selected, press cursor-right and the cursor-down several times, to select one of the recently opened remote hosts
- press RETURN

Result: RDC is opened, but the start menu stays open and the keyboard input goes to the start menu. When doing the same with Notepad and a recently open text file, after the RETURN key, start menu closes and the Notepad appears and gets focus.

Comment: Your description indicates profile damage to the Administrator User Account profile. You need to replace the user profile.

Comment: @John What exactly is the "Administrator User Account profile" and how to replace it? (why not write as an answer?)

Comment: Your "Administrator" Account is your first account. That is was I meant. But if all your accounts have this issue (not clear (to me) in your question, then replacing the User profile is not going to cure the issue. I will remove my answer because it does not apply at all.  My apologies.

Comment: OK, acknowledge...

Comment: I have determined what you are seeing and it is normal, if somewhat inconvenient behavior. It has been fixed in the upcoming version 20H2 (V2009).  I adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is "normal" behavior, at least on your machine V1909 and both my production machines V2004.  See my screenshot below. The issue has been fixed in V2009 (20H2). I tried the same thing as below on my Windows Insider 20H2 and it works properly, that is, has been fixed.

This issue also applies only if you are trying to start a normal program with admin permissions (not normally needed), but does not occur on a program that requires admin permissions.

I speculate that this occurs as a result of the extra step in Running as Admin, and then this is what has been fixed.

So you will need to click the Start Menu out of the way until the fall version of Windows comes out.

[image]

Comment: "Delete the Administrator Account"  I don't have an Administrator Account there. Do you mean my personal account?  Note that this problem appears with all user accounts.

Comment: Your "Administrator" Account is your first account. That is was I meant.  But if all your accounts have this issue (not clear (to me) in your question, then replacing the User profile is not going to cure the issue. I will remove my answer because it does not apply at all.

Comment: It happens regardless of program type: just click=OK, click "run as administrator"=start menu stays open

Comment: Once the app is open, click (only once) on it and the start menu goes away. Tested on both machines here. Nonetheless, the fix is coming in the Fall Windows version unless some future update fixes it. It is the way it is right now however.

Comment: I see this issue happening on 20H2 too.

Comment: Try a different user account (Standard or Admin) and see if the issue occurs on a new account. No issue here with 2 20H2 machines and 1 21H Insider machine.

Comment: I reinstalled since (version 21H1) and today updated to 21H2. Yet, the problem persists.